# Is there a way to test failover in amazonMQ?

Tags: node.js, amazon-mq

I'm testing the master-slave functionality of amazonMQ and I would like to trigger a failover under load and ensure that all messages sent are received by my subscribers.

I can't see any options in the gui or cli to trigger a failover scenario.  I have tried rebooting the broker but this affects both nodes.  Predictably this caused my test to fail as the standby broker was not available when my clients tried to reconnect.

There is some comfort in that my clients did try and reconnect to the standby broker immediately but I still can't be sure that all messages would get through if a failover scenario would occur.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: We have exactly the same need, it would be nice if AWS can provide a way to restart or stop just one node to test the failover.